# Soft links and Hard links

Tags: python, asp.net

Does a softlink still work if the file it links to is moved to a different location on the disk and why is that possible considering the action.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of file system, soft links will not work if the target it is pointing to has been moved/renamed/deleted.

It continues to points to the old target, now a non-existing location or file. Because symbolic link contains a text string that is automatically interpreted and followed by the operating system as a path to another file or directory called target.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to ask about python or *nix filesystems in general?